# Hibernate: criteria equivalent for order by field

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I'd like to have a criteria that would be equivalent with queries like these

```
SELECT name, population FROM bbc
  WHERE name IN ('Italy','France', 'Germany')
order by Field(name, 'Italy','France', 'Germany')
```

So what I need is to keep the order of the result that from an 'In' constraint.

I've found that one solution would be to inherit the Order class and write my own order criteria. The problem is that the criteria I use is very complex and I can't make it work using this method.

Is there another way to solve this problem?

I'm using hibernate version 3.6.10.Final and hibernate jpa version 1.0.1.Final.

Thanks.

Comment: what version of Hibernate/JPA are you using?

Comment: Please post what you have tried in order for us to help and make it work.

Comment: Did you find any answer to this?